# initState() not called when building stateful widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to build a widget and do something in the initState() function. I have done it before in other cases, but this time the initState() is just not called. I have put breakpoints, the application goes into the constructor (assert line) and the object in the assert is not null, so it should go on and initialize the state. But it doesn't, and I don't understand why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Here's the code:

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {

    SomeOtherObject someOtherObject;

    MyWidget({@required this.someOtherObject})
        :
            assert(someOtherObject != null)
    ;

    @override
    _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}


class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        // widget.someOtherObject.addListener(update);
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: So if you put a print() statement in initState, it won't print anything?

Comment: Nothing. I already tried it :) Doesn't stop in a breakpoint on that line, doesn't print anything.

Comment: Where are you using this widget?

Comment: So you know, initState doesn't get called on hot reload, only on hot restart.

Comment: @BenjaminS. yes, I know. As I said, it doesn't stop on breakpoint and there's nothing printed to the console.

Comment: @Abion47 In another stateful widget I have created. Debugger stops in the parent widget. Why would it make a difference where it's used ? Shouldn't a stateful's widget initState function be called at least once ?

Comment: The reason I ask is that the most likely reason would be because you're never actually building the widget. If the widget is built conditionally, for example, or is used inside a FutureBuilder or StreamBuilder that never resolves to the widget, or in a ListView where the widget is always off screen so never actually gets built, as some examples. Are you absolutely sure that the widget is being referenced, built, and is visible on the screen?

Comment: @Abion47 it's not conditional, and the constructor of the widget itself is called, as I mentioned. It's just the initState of the state class that's not called.

Comment: Have you tried constructing a [mcve] to reproduce the problem? As it stands, the code you've posted appears to be a typical `StatefulWidget` composition, so I have to assume that the issue lies somewhere in the code you did not post.

Comment: @Abion47 I will try to extract that. It's gonna be a bit difficult, I am afraid, but I will try.

Answer (score 1):

I would redirect you to this answer: [initState function is't be called in StatefulWidget by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54192066/initstate-function-ist-be-called-in-statefulwidget-by-default)

Your code works just fine in a DartPad, make sure you fully restart your app, not just hot reload. Often times for me, Flutter likes to use an old version of my app so I have to hot restart. Also, just so you know, any time you edit `initState()`, you MUST hot restart your app for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I know initState won't be called each time. I did even clear cache, storage, uninstall and restart it (in the emulator). Still the function is not getting called. :(

Comment: You answer are not wrong, but initState might not be called on some platform, down voted,.

Comment: Can you please point to where initState() isn't called on some platforms? There is no mention of that in any documentation.